# How does the communication with an HTTPS Web Proxy Work?

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, squid

I wish to setup an HTTPS proxy and have HTTP clients send requests securely to the proxy. For example, a browser can initiate a HTTP GET request which should be an encrypted request to the proxy and the proxy then removes the encryption and then passes the request to the end-site. Squid proxy can be set up to work like this (info [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Encrypted_browser-Squid_connection)).

I have set up such a HTTPS enabled proxy. But I am unable to write my own HTTP clients to work with it. The same link above mentions that chrome is the only browser that supports such a proxy. I tested Chrome and it was able to work with such an HTTPS proxy.

I wish to gain an understanding of how such a proxy works so that I can write my own HTTP clients.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, it's a connection to regular HTTP proxy BUT this connection is made over TLS. The client indeed needs to support this scheme explicitly and existing clients as-is can't be tuned up (without extra coding).

Comment: @eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp: Thanks for the reply. Are you aware of any Java libraries with Http Clients that support this scenario?

Comment: @MediumOne Unfortunately no. We will extend HTTP Client class of our SecureBlackbox (which has Java edition), but this will be done in future.

Comment: @eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp: I was able to make the Apache HttpClient support such a scenario. Please see my other question that I raised for this purpose - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048102/httprouteplanner-how-does-it-work-with-an-https-proxy